# Changing the range of FFT

Tags: matlab, fft

Let's say I have a vector of length 1000. If take the FFT of this data; MATLAB chooses the `k` values as `0:1:length(data)-1`. How can I change this range to `0:1:length(data)*(an integer)-1` or any desired range?

Answer (score 0):

See the [documentation to `fft`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html). The second parameter sets the size of the transform:

```
x = randn(1,1000);
y = fft(x,512);
```

However, this is equivalent to

```
y = fft(x(1:512));
```

That is, the input data is cropped to the right length, rather than using all the input data and computing only part of the output values.

There is no way to compute only part of the output values, as the FFT algorithm is most efficient when computing the full transform.

Alternatives are to simply crop the output (is the computation taking too long?), or to compute the DFT sample by sample (will be efficient only for a few output samples, anything more and your computation will take longer than the full FFT.

Comment: what about the extending the range of fft?say two time longer than the original length of the data? basically k values of fft would be (0:1:length(data)-1)/length(data). which is 0 to 1. how do I get 0 to 2?

Comment: By the way, basically I'm talking about the k values not calculating over a part of my data

Comment: Padding the input signal will lead to more frequency samples, but you’ll be interpolating in the frequency domain, not adding higher frequencies. Interpolating the input will add higher frequencies, but they’ll essentially be empty (anything you find there are interpolation artifacts) because you can’t obtain higher frequencies given a sampled signal. Any frequencies above Nyquist will have been aliased, a sampled signal contains no frequencies above Nyquist. So trying to get higher frequency samples in the frequency domain is futile.

Comment: Ok, now we are getting to same point, I'm trying to calculate the structure factor which is a physical concept. In the structure factor there is no limits on the k values. basically the data is just position of some particles not really a data recorded in time domain, so talking about the frequency of data is not relevant. Just google the structure factor and you see x axis is beyond 1. I can get the figures that I want with DFT and I can get beyond 1 and still everything seems perfect and actually not periodic! but in FFT after k value of 1 (Nyquist frequency)...

Comment: ... everything looks similar.  I know ur expertise is not physics but hope you could give me some insights on this difference between FFT and DFT. Structure factor is basically a fourier transform of paired correlation of particles...

Comment: @aaa The FFT is just a (family of) algorithms to compute the DFT (Discrete Fourier Transform). If your DFT yields frequencies above Nyquist that are different from those below Nyquist, you are not computing the DFT. The DFT is based on the idea that you have a limited set of equidistant samples of a signal, which transform in the same number of equidistant samples of the frequency spectrum of that signal.

Comment: @aaa With your data, a set of points (not samples of a continuous signal), it should be possible to estimate higher frequencies. Look into NFFT or NUFFT (Non-equidistant/Non-Uniform FFT). I believe this library is the most popular: https://www-user.tu-chemnitz.de/~potts/nfft/